# my html file path does not seem to want to work and from what I am aware everything is being done as it should be

Tags: html, button, onclick

[image: onclick does not open the folder]

When I use onclick on a button to send me to a new site inside of a folder it does not work and returns

```
Cannot GET /teamedit_teams.html
```

I know its to-do with the folder as I tested it without and I am quite stumped if anyone knows what's going on and could help that would be much appreciated also I am aware that it is possible that I am just being dumb and don't know what's going on lol

Comment: There's no way you'd get that result (the `/` disappearing between the URL in the JS and the 404 error page) from that code alone.

Comment: And don't use JavaScript to reinvent the wheel. HTML has the `<a>` element. It's the foundation of the WWW!

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular the part about not posting pictures of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You better create a document on path.

Your links are not the same. Location refers to `team/edit_teams.html`, but after you try `Cannot GET /teamedit_teams.html`.

If there is typo and links written correct, so check any js scripts, may be you have any listener binded to element id.

But why not use `<a href="team/edit_teams.html">Edit</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was it was I forgot to use a / in front of team and for the reason I never used an anchor tag welllll you see I never thought of that but thank you all for the help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).